# cant write in arabic after upgrading to ubuntu gnome 13.10

Tags: 13.10

after installing ubuntu gnome 13.10 I found that I cant write in arabic after changing keyboard layout to arabic (qwerty) the language indicator idicates that used language is arabic but it keep writing english !!!

Answer (score 0):

**Yes because you've to give the Arabic Layout to first preference**

- When you open Keyboard Layout, and add by <kbd>+</kbd> button a new layout, either you've to switch to it that or give it the first preference.
- You've to move **Arabic** layout on the top of the list, if needed you can try to remove the **English** layout and be with only to **Arabic** in the list, if still it doesn't help.
- You can switch to **English/Arabic** from the top-panel **Keyboard** applet-indicator sign, by clicking on it.

Hope you can understand me in this short description